# How to assign value to input variable in shell

Tags: shell-script, test, variable-substitution, parameter

I am asking user for input and taking input in the variables such as $1, $2 etc.
I am checking the variable for null value and wants to replace the value if null.

```
if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
2=value
fi
```

But something I am missing. Any suggestions?

Comment: [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Looks a bit like [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @MatthewRock There's a very clear use case which is to provide a default value for some parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly set values to the positional paramaters like this.

You *can* set them with the `set` command, but this will set *all* the values (`$1`, `$2`, ...)

e.g.

```
$ set -- first second third fourth fifth
$ echo $1
first
$ echo $2
second
```

Now there are two cases where `$2` can be the empty string; first if no value has been passed, or second if `""` is passed as an actual argument and so there may still be a `$3`, `$4` etc.

We can handle each case in a slightly complicated way:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Before 1=$1 2=$2 3=$3 4=$4

if [ -z "$2" ]
then
  first=$1
  shift 2
  set -- "$first" value "$@"
fi

echo After 1=$1 2=$2 3=$3 4=$4
```

The bit inside the `if` test will ensure all other values are retained.

e.g.

```
% ./testing arg1 "" "arg 3" "and arg 4"
Before 1=arg1 2= 3=arg 3 4=and arg 4
After 1=arg1 2=value 3=arg 3 4=and arg 4
```

But you might be able to do things simpler and just use `${2:-value}` which will evaluate to `value` if `$2` is not set, so then you don't need to worry about rewriting the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
   set "$1" value
fi
```

- see man test (an alternative is `[ "x$2" == x ]`
- set will position parameter, to position as second parameter, $1 must be recalled as first one.

Comment: why are you giving $1 in the second line while setting instead of $2?

Comment: @Aquarius24 Because `set "$1" value` doesn't set `$1` to `value`, it sets `$1` to `$1` (so `$1` is left unchanged) and `$2` to `value`. Similarly `set value` would set `$1` to value (and make `$2`, `$3`, etc. unset). `set one two three` sets `$1` to `one`, `$2` to `two` and `$2` to `three`.